# Collection repeat standalone directive

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is it possible to use the collection-repeat directive only with angularjs and without Ionic?
The directive is available at https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/directive/collectionRepeat.js .

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. But not in 10 seconds :)

**First**, include the directive file into your project, and transform this (L135) :

```
IonicModule
.directive('collectionRepeat', ...
```

Into this :

```
angular.module('yourModuleName')
.directive('collectionRepeat', ...
```

**Then**, copy too the two ionic dependencies of `collectionRepeat` which are [`$collectionRepeatManager`](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/18775ae169e099d82202bc66b9210113d07171d5/js/angular/service/collectionRepeatManager.js) and [`$collectionDataSource`](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/js/angular/service/collectionRepeatDataSource.js), repeating the same modification.

You should be done.

Comment: It's not working anymore. Any idea on how to do this now ? There is a dependency to $ionicScroll :(

Comment: Hi - were you able to make this work in AngularJS?